# How do I traverse a generic relationship in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, generic-relationship

I would like to traverse generic relationships in my Django template, similar to how you can traverse FK relationships.

Models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

This does not seem to work in my template:

```
{{ company.address_set.all }}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read your own code again. Why would company have an address_set?

Comment: I guess that's my question. If I were to specify a foreign key relationship in `Address` that pointed to `Company`, then `Company` would have an address_set. So, I would like to know how I can accomplish the same thing with a generic relationship, since `Address` can be associated with `Company` or a host of other models.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Company model doesnt know about the adresses, you could try this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    addresses = generic.GenericRelation('Address', blank = True)
```

In your template you can do something like this :

```
{% for address in company.addresses.all %}
{{ address.town }}, {{ address.street }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps.